# How to restore deleted device mapper?

Tags: linux, partition

Accidentally, device mapper has been deleted from `Integrated storage`.

`kpartx -s -d -p X /dev/mapper/5lvdja6xen3oks`

Is there a way to restore this data?

Answer (score 0):

That command does not delete the *device mapper* (a kernel sub-system). Only the *mappings* created to access the partitions within your device would be removed.

Those mappings are not persistent and are created by `kpartx` according to the partition table on your storage device, each time you boot your system. So *if the partition table on the RAID set is undamaged*, you could just recreate the mappings by just replacing the `-d` (delete) option with `-a` (add):

```
kpartx -s -a -p X /dev/mapper/5lvdja6xen3oks
```

Or you could just reboot the system and it would probably start up just fine again.

(From the device name, I guess the device is using DM-RAID, which usually has a partition table within the RAID set - the more common MD software RAID usually works the opposite way, having individual partitions within partitioned disks used as RAID elements, and each MD RAID set would then contain just one filesystem.)

**However,** if `kpartx` cannot recreate the missing partition mappings, it would indicate that the partition table on the device has been overwritten, or that the "whole-disk" RAID set device `/dev/mapper/5lvdja6xen3oks` is not accessible for some reason. To verify the state of the RAID set, you should probably use the `dmraid -r` and/or `dmraid -s` commands. If you need more help on this, please edit your original question and add the outputs of these commands into the original question post.

If only the partition table has been overwritten, `testdisk` or a similar tool (e.g. `testdisk /dev/mapper/5lvdja6xen3oks`) could be used to read through the whole-disk device, find the endpoints of each partition and rebuild the partition table, after which `kpartx` could again used to make the partitions accessible.